# Terraform provisioner local_exec file not found using EOT

Tags: terraform

I wish to execute a command in Terraform on resource creation that requires a file.
The command executes perfectly when using it in a oneliner like `command = "<COMMAND>"`.

However, because the command is quite long, I wish to use `EOT` and create a multi-line command with the `\` seperator.
Now, it doesn't recognise any file I need, but it did before using the oneliner (Command below is just an example).

```
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
    command = <<-EOT
      cat .state/test.txt
    EOT
  }
```

I throws the following error:

```
│ Error running command 'cat .state/test.txt
│ ': exit status 1. Output: cat: '.state/test.txt'$'\r': No such file or directory
```

while the file does exists?

Any help in understanding is appreciated.

Comment: Where is the `state` directory located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess that the `state` directory is in the same directory you are running terraform code from, so this should be an easy fix:

```
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
    command = <<-EOT
      cat ./state/test.txt
    EOT
  }
```

Alternatively, you could do the following:

```
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
    command = <<-EOT
      cat "${path.root}/state/test.txt"
    EOT
  }
```

More information about using `path` based variables can be found in [1].

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/references#filesystem-and-workspace-info

Comment: Although it's a logical solution, absolute paths doesn't make it working either. I think the error resides in the `$'\r` at the end of the file path, which I don't know where it comes from.

Comment: Linux vs Windows?

Comment: What is the directory structure?

Comment: I operate with Windows WSL (for now).
Actually, I want to run Ansible from within Terraform, but using the method above it cannot find the playbook.
I found out about an [Ansible provisioner](https://github.com/radekg/terraform-provisioner-ansible) , which is much cleaner than the way I intended to do.

Comment: So, I see this problem as 'solved', but if I can gain insights in why the error is thrown, I'm all ears.

Comment: As I've said, I think it has something to do with the CRLF vs LF. If you saved the code in an IDE where CRLF is set and tried to run it in bash, then it won't work as expected. However, you could add everything to a shell script (instead of multiline commands), run `dos2unix` and the error should be gone.

Comment: Altough I'v used `dos2unix` before, I didn't apply it on the Terraform docs, which was the solution. Thank you for bringing it up once again. This was something I should've known myself.

Comment: Besides, I thought about scripting mysqelf, but I need Terraform generated values for it, so I need to pass them to the script anyway. I'm satisfied with the Ansible provisioner.